# MySQL Trigger UPDATE another table

Tags: mysql

I use **mysql 5.7** and the structure of database is as the picture below.

[image]

***I want the colum "Course_left1" on table Course to drop by 1 whenever a course log is inserted into the table Course_history***，but it's not working.

```
CREATE TRIGGER Course_reduce
AFTER INSERT ON Course_history
FOR EACH ROW
    UPDATE Course SET Course.Course_left1 = (Course.Course_left1 - 1) where NEW.Sid = Course.Sid
```

[image: Sample data for table Course]

Sid stands for the id of Student while Course_left1 and Course_left2 stand for the course remain for the specific student.

[image: Sample data for table Course_history]

Now, if I insert one tuple into table Course_history I want the Course_left1 in the table Course to drop by 1 which makes it 31.

Comment: What problem are you really trying to solve?

Comment: Maybe flip your `WHERE` condition from `where NEW.Sid = Course.Sid` to `where Course.Sid = NEW.Sid`

Comment: @IgorIlic Tried, not working

Comment: Apart from a missing terminator the trigger works as coded. If you don't think it does it would be helpful if you added sample data and expected outcome.

Comment: @Strawberry The bold and iatic words in the quetion elaborate what I am tring to do.

Comment: Yeah - I meant at a higher level.

Comment: Works fine see https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aNTEosvtJCCroYtJcg1BzD/0

Comment: @P.Salmon Descriptions added.

Comment: Your trigger is absolutely correct. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=77d1d27aebf3312bf0cb8a2601fe7321).

Comment: *Now, if I insert one tuple into table Course_history I want the Course_left1 in the table Course to drop by 1 which makes it 31.* You must insert not tuple, but tuple with `Sid = 6` strongly!

Comment: Your process seems to be that whenever a course_history record is inserted EVERY student on course should be reduced by 1?

Comment: @P.Salmon It did work with the new test database I created. But on my old database it still isn't working. Is there something wrong with the Foreign Key constraint when I created the tables?

Comment: What version of mysql is your old database - also I doubt FKs have anything to do with it

Comment: @P.Salmon Tested with 2 Students. Works fine with the constraint of WHERE  clause.

Comment: You mean the problem has gone away?

Comment: @P.Salmon I recreated the two tables(Course and Course_history) and now the problem is gone. My conclusion is that there could be something wrong with the FKs. You can take a look at the database structure. Both of the two tables concerning in the trigger have different lengths with the key Sid in the table Student.